# Ask a question on Helmert matrix $L'L=I_{n}-\frac{1}{n}1 1'$

Tags: linear-algebra

\begin{align}
H=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}&\cdots&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}
\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0&0&\cdots&0&0
\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}&-\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}&0&\cdots&0&0
\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots
\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}&\cdots&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}&\frac{-(n-1)}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

The above is the general form of the Helmert matrix. I can use block to express matrix. The first row is ($\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},...,\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$). The remaining $(n-1)\times n$ matrix is denoted L. I can understand $LL'=I_{n-1}$, where $L'$ means transpose of $L$. But how can I see $L'L=I_{n}-\frac{1}{n}1 1'$, where 1 is the column vector all 1's.

Comment: You have defined $H$, but what is $L$?

Comment: @user1551 the L is submatrix of H except the first row of H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to believe if you take it as given that the Helmert matrix is orthogonal, i.e. $H'H = HH' = I_n$. This seems particularly believable since the rows of the Helmert matrix can be obtained by following the Gram Schmidt process on the basis
$$
(1,1,1,\dots,1,1), \quad (0,-1,0,\dots,0,0), \quad \dots\quad   (0,0,0,\dots,0,-1).
$$
Given that $H$ is orthogonal, we can conclude that the rows of $L$ are mutually orthonormal, which is to say that $LL' = I_{n-1}$, as you have already said. From this, we can conclude that $L'L$ must be an orthogonal projection matrix. Indeed, $P = L'L$ is a symmetric (Hermitian) matrix satisfying
$$
P^2 = (L'L)^2 = L'(LL')L = L'L = P.
$$
The space that $P$ projects onto is its column space, which is the rowspace of $L$. However, since $H$ is an orthogonal matrix with its first row equal to $\mathbf 1/\sqrt{n}$, the row space of $L$ must be the orthogonal complement of the space spanned by $\mathbf 1$. Since $\mathbf 1 \mathbf 1'/n$ is the matrix of the projection onto the span of $\mathbf 1$, $P$ must be the projection $I_n - \mathbf 1\mathbf 1'/n$.

Answer (score 0):

Denote $c_k$ the column $k$ of matrix $L$. Then we have
$$c_k =\begin{pmatrix}
0& \ldots & 0 & \frac{-(k-1)}{\sqrt{(k-1)k}}&  \frac{1}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}} &\ldots&  \frac{1}{\sqrt{(n-1)n}} 
\end{pmatrix}$$
The $ij$-entry of matrix $L'L$ equals to $c_i \cdot c_j$. There are two cases:

- Case 1: $i=j$. We have
  \begin{align}
  c_i \cdot c_i &= \frac{(i-1)^2}{(i-1)i}+\frac{1}{i(i+1)}+\frac{1}{(i+1)(i+2)}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(n-1)n}\\
  &=1-\frac{1}{i}+\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{i+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\\
  &=1-\frac{1}{n}
  \end{align}
- Case 2: $i>j$
  \begin{align}
  c_i \cdot c_j &= \frac{-(i-1)}{(i-1)i}+\frac{1}{i(i+1)}+\frac{1}{(i+1)(i+2)}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(n-1)n}\\
  &=-\frac{1}{i}+\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{i+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\\
  &=-\frac{1}{n}
  \end{align}
  So we have $L'L = I_n-\frac{1}{n}1 1'$.